# Return from rails controller on timeout, while waiting and processing response from webservice called in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, http-post

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.content_type p= 'text/xml'
request.body = websvcRQ.result(binding).gsub("\n","")
# need to set the read timeout for http POST
response= http.request(request)
# return from controller after some timeout, but keep waiting for the response (could be 3 mins)
```

---

I do the above within a begin-catch, but return with the POST response failure directly in the controller on timeout. What I need is a way for the controller to return a failure status to the webservice client (for the datanoise/RoR server), while we continue to wait until a longer read timeout with the external webservice which sometimes takes 3 minutes to respond. That response needs to be processed and stored in the database (simple update one column in mysql).

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I'm using Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7 on RHEL5.

Comment: Calls to webservices should be made in background

Comment: I'm new to RoR - a pointer to an example would help....I was also trying to look for threads examples, but wasnt clear how they worked within the rails/datanoise actionwebservice controller.

Comment: Look at delayed_job or resque